# Calabash-ios: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore

Tags: ios, nativescript, calabash, calabash-ios

I have an application developed using NativeScript+AngularJS which I need to do some automated UI testing on a physical device. I am using Calabash for this and it worked out of the box for my Android version but i'm having some difficulties with the IOS version.

I have followed the setup guide [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Testing-on-Physical-Devices) and [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Link-Calabash-in-Debug-config) and completed each step. I can query everything on the screen when running `bundle exec calabash-ios console` so the calabash server is running on the phone. When trying to execute the command `start_test_server_in_background` I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBControlCore.framework/Versions/A/FBControlCore
>       Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.4.1/lib/run_loop/device_agent/bin/iOSDeviceManager
>       Reason: image not found

And when I try to run the command `APP=< path to .app generated by NativeScript > DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.254.208:37265 DEVICE_TARGET=9d7929c174c0f8f11408a834a258ac2af3 bundle exec cucumber`

I get the same error noted before.

Have tried:

- The command above with the specified bundle id for the application but with no different outcome.
- The command above with APP=< path to .app generated by XCode >
- Manually importing the FBControlCore.framework in both XCode and the NativeScript IOS build.xcconfig file

Device Information:

- IPhone 6s
- IOS version 10.2.1